# Remover substring com regex

Tags: jquery, regex

Tenho a string:

```
var str = "Quantidade [12]";
```

Preciso recuperar a string mas remover o espaço e o [12], ou seja, preciso ter como retorno apenas o valor: **Quantidade**.

No caso da string ser `var str = "Quantidade máxima [12]";`, preciso obter todo o texto à esquerda do colchete, ou seja, o valor **Quantidade máxima**.

Tanto o tamanho das strings quanto o valor entre os colchetes podem mudar, a máscara seria basicamente:

```
var str = "string [*]";
```

Sempre terei somente esse par de colchetes e um valor numérico dentro. Como consigo recuperar toda a string removendo o espaço e o valor numérico?

Answer (score 1):

**Utilizando expressões regulares**

Os últimos espaços acabam permanecendo. A função *trim()* remove os espaços no final.

```
var regexp = new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z ]+/);
regexp.exec("Quantidade máxima [12]").trim(); // "Quantidade máxima"
```

**Manipulando com substring**

Para incluir o exemplo citado "Quantidade máxima", você pode manipular a string diretamente:

```
var valor = "Quantidade máxima [12]"; 
var resultado = val.substring(0, val.indexOf("[") - 1); // "Quantidade máxima"
```

Comment: Mas quando tiver algo como "Quantidade máxima [12]", preciso que seja retornado "Quantidade máxima" sem o colchetes, número e nem o ultimo espaço.

Comment: essa informação está lá, informo que o tamanho da strings pode mudar e inclusive sugeri o que seria uma mascara.

Answer (score 1):

Se o padrão que tens é `string` +  + `[*]` parece-me que um `.split()` chega.

Podes fazer assim, sem precisar de RegExp:

```
var str = "Quantidade [12]";
var texto = str.split(' ')[0];
```

Se queres mesmo usar regex, bastaria `/(\w+)/`, ou seja:

```
var str = "Quantidade [12]";
var texto = str.match(/(\w+)/)[0];
```